# Child' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I try to implement keeping URL parameters in path and I have such function:

```
function Child({ name }: { name: string }) {
  //display review information
  if (name === 'review-information') {
    return <></>;
  }

  //display summary tab
  if (name === 'summary') {
    return <></>;
  }
}
```

This is a way how I call the function:

```
<Child name={query.get('name') as string} />
```

But I got error like this one:

[image]

> Its return type 'Element|undefined' is not a valid JSX element.

How to solve it?

Comment: What if the `name` is neither `'review-information'` nor `'summary'`?

Comment: I just wanted to write "let's leave it, it is not a part of my question" but...I added "else" and it works! Thanks!

Comment: You can't return `undefined` (e.g. not returning) in a React component. Add `return null` at the end of your component.

Comment: You could alternatively have told TypeScript that those options were exhaustive, e.g. by having a narrower type for `name`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you propose more narrower type?

Comment: `'review-information' | 'summary'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have code paths which do not return values. You can either be more specific on the type, or always return some value:

```
function Child({ name }: { name: string }) {
  //display review information
  if (name === 'review-information') {
    return <></>;
  }

  //display summary tab
  if (name === 'summary') {
    return <></>;
  }

  return <p>Some sort of return value here</p>
}
```

or...

```
function Child({ name }: { name: 'review-information' | 'summary' }) {
  //display review information
  if (name === 'review-information') {
    return <></>;
  }


  // ts knows that name must equal 'summary' now
  return <></>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `else` in the loop:

```
function Child({ name }: { name: string }) {
  //display review information
  if (name === 'review-information') {
    return <></>;
  }

  //display summary tab
  if (name === 'summary') {
    return <></>;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```